# How to mock com.google.common.collect.Iterators.partition() in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, iterator

I am trying to write unit test for the below method "processStudentData".

```java
@Override
public List<StudentsCSV> processStudentData(MappingIterator<Students> studentsMappingIterator, String studentDetails) {
    // ...

    Iterators.partition(studentsMappingIterator, BATCH_SIZE)
        .forEachRemaining(studentsList -> processBatch(studentDetails.getStudentId()));

    List<StudentsCSV> studentsCSVList = new ArrayList();
    // ...
    return studentsCSVList;
}
```

I have used com.google.common.collect.Iterators.partition() inside this method. And I tried to mock is as below, but it doesn't work. I want to know how to write unit tests for "processStudentData" method?

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class AudienceDataProcessorServiceTest {

    @Test
    void test(){
        List<Students>  studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Students student = new Students();
        studentsList.add(student);
        Iterator<Students> iteratorStudent = studentsList.iterator();

        Iterators iterators = mock(Iterators.class);
        when(iterators.partition(any(MappingIterator.class),anyInt())).thenReturn(Iterators.unmodifiableIterator(iteratorStudent));
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you don't mock it?

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to mock it. Doing so hardly makes any sense. The purpose of a test is to verify that a method does what it is supposed to do. If you mock the iterator, you're not doing that, instead you're testing if the implementation uses that specific iterator. You should prepare a specific set of data, and maybe mock other external sources of data, and then verify if the returned data is what you expected.